# How to send 10000 POST requests fast in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, grequests

```
import requests

for i in range(100):
    data = ("test=test")
    header = {"header":"dasdasddasd"}
    x = requests.post("http://example.com", data=data, headers=header)
    print(x)
```

I want send 10000 requests in 10 min or more, but not more than 60 min!

I already try grequests but i can't get response content!

Comment: You'll need to implement threading. Make requests in parallel, maybe in batches of 100. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16761286/1023432

Comment: please, post your attempt with `grequests` or remove redundant tag

Comment: i explain what is my problem with grequests, it's i can't get response content, maybe someone help me !

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, Google has enough means of protecting against such DDOS attacks, like you are trying to perform. And I believe you are likely to get banned on google.com for some period or at least would fall into human checking. I hope, you are not using corporate IP address :)

Usually when someone provides online services, you should get a special subscription and use subscription token to get better QOS. Noone would just serve thousands of requests from noname endpoint.

Comment: It's just example, didn't want DDOS attack! 

Comment: I'm just telling any public server would stop responding to you after some amount of requests. Probably, that is your problem?

Comment: No, i will use this code for test something in my website :)

Thanks